# Agent based modelling in Python: defining a step method with timestep as its argument

Tags: python, agent-based-modeling

I am using the "mesa" library of Python to define an agent based model. I am encountering a problem when I define the step method of the agents and of the model. In particular I would like the agents to behave in a certain way if they act during the first time step of the simulation, and in a different way if the timestep in which they operate is after the first one.
The way I am trying to implement this is (the following is the agent step method):

```
def step(self, timestep):
    if timestep == 0:
       self.behaviour_1()
    else self.behaviour_2()
```

The model step method would be:

```
def step(self, timestep):
    self.schedule.step(timestep)
    self.datacollector.collect(self)
```

The run file would be structured:

```
for i in range(15):
    model.step(i)
```

Unfortunately when I run this I get an error saying: "step() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given".
How do I solve this?

Comment: It looks like you should not be passing `timestep` to the `step` method of your schedule.